# And together columns of logical matrix together to get one vector

Tags: r

I want to take a logical matrix and `and` all of the columns in the matrix together to create a vector. An example:

```
a = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
A = matrix(a, nrow = 3, ncol = TRUE, byrow = TRUE)
```

I would like to produce

```
[1] TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
```

Currently I am doing this with

```
apply(A, 1, function(x) Reduce('&', x))
```

However, this goes very slow with the size of my input, and I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be faster to use:

```
apply(A,1,all)
```

instead of a call to `Reduce`.

Also, the `rowSums` function is equivalent to `apply(x,1,sum)` but much faster, so it will probably be even faster to do:

```
rowSums(A)==ncol(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Reduce` within `apply`, an option would be to either convert the 'A' to `data.frame` and then do

```
Reduce(`&`, as.data.frame(A))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

---

Or `split` by `col` and then

```
Reduce(`&`, split(A, col(A)))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```